# Wolfram Derivation Error

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to derive the equation

$$y = (2x-6)^4$$

I thought that it would be

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 8(2x-6)^3$$

Wolframalpha says $dy/dx = 64(x-3)^3$

Who's correct? I thought it would be a simple calc-1 chain rule.

Comment: factor out the $2$ in $(2x-6)$.

Comment: @Tao Comments are to "ask for more information or suggesting improvements". Please avoid answering questions in the comments section.

Comment: @Fly: Oh for heaven's sake.

Comment: @TonyK These are the community guidelines. Answering questions in the comments section undermines the entire system.

Comment: @Fly: You see "factor out the $2$ in $(2x-6)$" as a threat to the system? You need to get a sense of proportion.

Comment: Oh, yeah...it's been years since I've done any real math. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TonyK If you want to play the game then play by the rules. If you don't want to play by the rules then don't play the game.

Comment: @Fly: you're saying that I should refrain from posting on this site because I think that it was OK for Tao to post that comment?

Comment: @TonyK I'm saying that if you want to post on this site then you should follow the rules of this site. If you don't want to follow the rules of this site then you ought to find another site. I think that this is perfectly reasonable and logical.

Comment: @Fly: Unbelievable.

Comment: @Fly by Night: I dont see my comment as "answering the question", you still need to try to factor it by yourself,

Comment: @Tao Yes, you're right, you do have to make the factorisation $2x-6 \equiv 2(x-3)$.

Comment: Children...please cut it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$[f(g(x))]'=g'(x)f'(g(x))$$
Taking $f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=2x-6$:
$$[(2x-6)^4]'=(2x-6)'4(2x-6)^3=8(2x-6)^3=8(2(x-3))^3=64(x-3)^3$$

As you can see they are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=8(2x-6)^3=8(2(x-3))^3=8\cdot(2^3(x-3)^3)=64(x-3)^3$$

As demostrated above, from the result you obtained to that obtained by Wolfram Alpha. As you can see, they are both equal.

Comment: Is minus not plus in the second and next sides of the equation

Comment: thanks for that,I'll fix it

Answer (score -1):

There is no error. There is a common fact of $2$ in $(2x-6)$. That means we can write
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2x-6)^4 &\equiv& \left[2(x-3)\right]^4 \\ \\
&\equiv& 2^4\cdot(x-3)^4 \\ \\
&\equiv& 16(x-3)^4
\end{eqnarray*}
If you differentiate this then you will get what $64(x-3)^3$ as Wolfram Alpha gives you.

Alternatively, if you differentiate first then you have
\begin{eqnarray*}
8(2x-6)^3 &\equiv& 8\left[2(x-3)\right]^3 \\ \\
&\equiv& 8\cdot 2^3\cdot(x-3)^3 \\ \\
&\equiv& 64(x-3)^3
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Why is it a good idea to answer the same thing as others at a later time?

Comment: @KevinBrown I felt that the other answers were opaque and lacked clarity. My intention was to give a more detailed and step-by-step reply to your question.

Comment: Whoever down voted this post is either illiterate or spiteful. Downvotes are for answers which are "not useful". My reply answers the OP's question precisely and so is of some use.